# Calling web3.eth.getAccounts() does nothing - no errors

Tags: truffle, nodejs, infura, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I am trying to get all accounts using `web3@1.3.3` and `@truffle/hdwallet-provider@1.2.2`. I am using `HDWalletProvider` with **Infura**. I am running this code on backend (**Node.js v14.15.5**). This is the code that I have currently:

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase: '... 12 words ...'
  },
  providerOrUrl: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID'
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider.engine);

const deploy = async (contractName) => {
  try {
    console.log('checkpoint 1');
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(e) {
      console.log('checkpoint 2');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('checkpoint 3');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Checkpoint 4');
  }
};

deploy('myContract');
```

When I run the code, the only thing printed into console is `checkpoint 1`. There is no error or exception, no indication that something wrong. Can somebody give me a hint what I am doing wrong? Why is `getAccounts` not working?

***EDIT***

I also tried the following code (as per *smarteasy* suggestion), but it doesn't work either. It only prints `checkpoint 1`:

```js
const deploy = async (contractName) => {
  try {
    console.log('checkpoint 1');
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('checkpoint 2');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('checkpoint 3');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap `deploy()` function in `async`

```
(async () => {
    deploy('myContract');
})();
```

In general I prefer to use [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/overview) for contacts testing and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It's declared as async, so use await.
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Please see my edited question.